# Apache Isis vs JSON Presentation

Tags: isis

I am working on building a sample web application for proof of concept - with a link of some sort on an html page consuming a restful web service via a json object and displaying the data on the web page .

Something like the Apache Isis todo maintenance  version with presentation of the json representation on a web page.

I have been trying to use the JQueryMobile example of the Apache Isis (http://danhaywood.com/2012/01/20/jquerymobile-on-apache-isis-rest-api/). But, I do not have the original source code (only the war file with some online demo jar files in the lib). I could decompile the online demo jar files, but its not straight forward setting up the project in eclipse for adapting to a real life project. I searched the Isis github repo and could not find the source , no archtype like the simple wicket etc. Please, could someone help, I really need a sample app or references, with source file and or any kind of guideline on how this works end to end.

FYI - We are not considering changing the choice of technology here, Its DDD using Apache Isis. Any help will be appreciated ... Since there are not too many online tutorials or sample app on this project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you posted a similar question on my youtube channel.  Just to reiterate what I said there, you might want to check out the JQueryMobile viewer that was developed by one of our "google summer of code" students last year, namely https://github.com/bhargavgolla/isisJavaScript/tree/master/isisJavaScriptViewer.

In terms of ongoing help, your best bet is subscribing to the mailing list (blank email to users-subscribe@isis.apache.org, and reply to the confirmation) then send your questions via email to users@isis.apache.org

HTH
Dan